# Prove $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] /(a + \sqrt{d}) \cong\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, where $n=|a^2-d|$.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, normed-spaces, quadratic-integer-rings

Let $a,d$ be integers with $d$ square free.  Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]/(a + \sqrt{d}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $n= |a^2- d|.$

I've tried attempting the problem by looking for a surjective homomorphism with kernel $(a + \sqrt{d})$.  I thought about using the standard norm $N(x + y\sqrt{d}) = |x^2 - dy^2|$ but its not additive, I'm also not sure it's surjective.

This isn't homework, I'm just looking up practice problems to study for an exam.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want a ring homomorphism, so $1 \mapsto 1$, and $(1+1) \mapsto (1+1)$ etc. Show that that gives an isomorphism.

Comment: I'll give it a try thanks

Answer (score 1):

$${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{d}] / (a + \sqrt{d}) \cong {\mathbb Z}[X]/(X^2 -d, a + X) \cong {\mathbb Z}/(a^2 -d) = {\mathbb Z}/(|a^d - d|).$$
The second isomorphism is induced by the homomorphism ${\mathbb Z}[X] \to {\mathbb Z}$ sending $X$ to $-a$; under that map the ideal $(X^2 - d, a+X)$ of ${\mathbb Z}[X]$ corresponds to the ideal $(a^2 - d)$ of ${\mathbb Z}$.